# Appending to a Textfile while keeping the stored data in the TextFile

Tags: java, eclipse, io, append

```
public static void InandOut() {


    Scanner scnThree = new Scanner(System.in);
    String days[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

    for(int iNum = 0; iNum < days.length; iNum++){
        System.out.printf("Enter time-in for %s: ", days[iNum]);
        timein = scnThree.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("Enter time-out for %s: ", days[iNum]);
        timeout = scnThree.nextLine();

        String strIn[] = timein.split(":");
        float intIn[] = new float[strIn.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < intIn.length; i++) {
            intIn[i] = Integer.parseInt(strIn[i]);
        }

        float minutesIn = intIn[1] / 60;
        float hoursIn = intIn[0] + minutesIn;

        String strOut[] = timeout.split(":");
        float intOut[] = new float[strOut.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < intOut.length; i++){
            intOut[i] = Integer.parseInt(strOut[i]);
        }

        float minutesOut = intOut[1] / 60;
        float hoursOut = intOut[0] + minutesOut;

        late = hoursIn - 8;
        undertime = 17 - hoursOut;
        dailyworkhours = 8 - (late + undertime);
        totalLate += late;
        totalUndertime += undertime;
        totalNumberofWorkHours += dailyworkhours;



        try{
            oFile = new Formatter("DTR.txt");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("You've got an error!");
        }

        oFile.format("\n%s\t %s\t %s", days[iNum], timein, timeout);

        oFile.close();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter the coverage date of this payroll: ");
    coverDate = scnThree.nextLine();
}
```

How can I append to a textfile while not affecting the stored data in the textfile? this is only an excerpt of my codes. The method above should input the time in and time out hour in the textfile every loop but it only replaces the stored data in the textfile. This always pop up.

[image: DTR.txt pop-up]

Comment: A `FileWriter` has a constructor `FileWriter(File file, boolean append)` where you have to set `append` to `true`.

Comment: You will always get the message from the Eclipse Text Editor if you change the text file outside of Eclipse while the editor is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `FileOutpuStream` to setup the stream, this will allow to specify that you want to append to the current file

```
    try (Formatter oFile = new Formatter(new FileOutputStream("DTR.txt", true))) {
        //...
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Have a look at [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) for more deatils

You may also like to take a look at [try-catch-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which will help make your life easier